# How can I make a function which calculates the weekday of a specific date in C?

Tags: c, dayofweek

Fixed:
I had to do it with a pointer to call the values(I also changed the formular but I´m sure the old one would also work. The problem was the missing pointer):

```
sAppointment Calendar[MAXAPPOINTMENTS];

int dayOfWeek(sDate *date){
    static int jMonth[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
    int d = date->Day;
    int m = date->Month;
    int y = date->Year;

    if(m < 3) y--;

    return(y + (y/4) - (y/100) + (y/400) + jMonth[m - 1] + d) % 7;
}
```

---

I am writing a C Program which has a datastructure in which the variables of a date can be saved but it does not work for the weekday.
It appears an error: "expression must have integral type"

The function is build like this, including a formular to calculate the weekday:

```
void dayOfWeek(sDate date){
    if(date.Month > 3) date.Year = date.Year - 1;
    date.WeekDay = ((date.Day + floor (2.6 * ((date.Month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 0.2) + date.Year % 100 + floor (date.Year % 100 / 4) + floor (date.Year / 400) - 2 * floor (date.Year / 100) - 1) % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
}
```

The date datastructure contents int values which looks like this (german language):

```
typedef enum {So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa} eDayofTheWeek;

typedef struct{
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
    eDayofTheWeek WeekDay;
} sDate;
```

I tried to set most of the formular to a variable which first containts everything before the modulo operator

```
int w;
w = ((date.Day + floor (2.6 * ((date.Month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 0.2) + date.Year % 100 + floor (date.Year % 100 / 4) + floor (date.Year / 400) - 2 * floor (date.Year / 100) - 1);
date.Weekday =( w % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
```

This only led to the weekday value being 0. Other formulars also let the value of being 0.

Comment: Needs more variables or something.  Why `+ 1` on `Weekday`?  0 = `So`.

Comment: Plit up the complex calculation of `w` into its smallest parts, and store the result in temporary variables. That way it's *much* easier to debug and look at what the calculations are and where they go wrong.

Comment: And why `if(date.Month > 3) date.Year = date.Year - 1;`? That makes no sense. The year is the year, no matter the month.

Comment: That formula is a monster, really hard to understand and debug - which is exactly your problem. At the very least the part that deals with leap years should be extracted to a separate function, which can be tested on its own.

Comment: And what's the point of `( w % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1`? Seems like `( w % 7) + 1` would do the same. Not to mention `floor (2.6 * ((date.Month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 0.2)` - I don't have the *remotest* idea of what that part is doing. I would never let this code pass a review.

Comment: Hello, I apologize for the formular. I did not wrote it but found it. My problem is, that even if I find a similar formular or even functions like the day_of_week function here 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954575/formatting-a-calendar-in-c' the value of my enum stays 0. If there are any suggestions to why this is happening (for example a false use of the enum function) or an idea/reference for a way to get the weekday of my datasructure, I would be very greatful.

Comment: You have 3 choices: 1) Try to understand and debug this formula 2) Find another one, which is easier to understand and that works correctly 3) Write your own. I'd choose the second one, or maybe the third one if finding a working function turned out to be too hard (which would surprise me). But I'd never choose the first one. There's too much magic in it. For example, the way I'd approach this is: start from a known day (like: today, 2023-12-05, is Tuesday), then calculate how many days there are between the given date and the known one, and then calculate the week day. The function you have,

Comment: instead, doesn't do that. It seems to calculate the day of the week without counting the days from a reference day. How does that work? I have no idea. That's why I say there's too much magic in it. Just forget it.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: For Linux, see also: [Retrieve Linux Time using `struct timespec`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47532135/4561887). In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889097/4561887) I use `strftime()` to turn a `struct tm` into the string `Fri Apr 15 14:05:12 2022 -0700`. You can easily modify my `time_format_str` to just get `Friday`, for instance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “And why `if(date.Month > 3) date.Year = date.Year - 1;`? That makes no sense. The year is the year, no matter the month.”: Some algorithms to calculate dates rebase the year to start on March 1 because then the map from (month, day) to (day of year) is invariant. With a year starting on January 1, the number of the day of the year varies by 1 for dates in March and later due to leap years. But then I would expect the test to be `>= 3` or `>= 2`, depending on whether month numbering starts with January as 1 or 0. And to make the year later, not earlier…

Comment: … Maybe it is a typo and should be `<` instead of `>`? That would fix both the month numbering and the adjustment direction.

Comment: For various commenters: The formula is a [classic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Disparate_variation) for calculating the day of the week.

Comment: @Angargedon --thanks for raising this question!  It has been one of the more rewarding colabs on Stackoverflow I've found.  Hope you can use one of the answers or suggestions... kind regards

Comment: Suggest using 2.6001 instead of 2.6.  Zeller's congruence has rounding errors on 32 bit floating point.

Comment: @cup: Or use `* 13 / 5`. The calculation can be rewritten to remove the `0.2` and use only integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's code has at least these problems:

**No update for caller**

`void dayOfWeek(sDate date){` does not provide any result back to the caller ("This only led to the weekday value being 0").  Instead, pass by reference.

```
void dayOfWeek(sDate *date) {
//                   ^
```

**`%` not valid with floating point**

Before applying `%`, convert the value to an `int`.  Note: C does not has a modulo operator but a [*remainder* operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359).

**Wrong test**

```
// if(date.Month > 3)   date.Year = date.Year - 1;
if(date.Month < 3) { date.Year = date.Year - 1;  maybe adjust Month }
```

---

I was unable to fully fix OP's code.

Consider avoiding one-liner code and instead provide more clarity.

Below works for month and day outside the usual range.

```
#define MARCH 3
#define DaysPer400Years   (400*365LL + 97)
#define DaysPer100Years   (100*365LL + 24)
#define DaysPer4Years     (4*365LL + 1)
#define DaysPer1Year      365LL
#define DayNumber1970Jan1 719469
#define MonthsPerYear 12

long long DayNumber0(int year, int Month, int Day, long epoch) {
  long long dn = Day;
  long long y = year;
  y += Month / 12;
  Month %= 12;
  while (Month < MARCH) {
    Month += 12;
    y--;
  }
  // And then a miracle occurs. Scale by 30.59375 and add an offset.
  dn += ((Month - MARCH) * (7832 / 4) + (140 / 4)) >> (8 - 2);
  dn += (y / 400) * DaysPer400Years;
  y %= 400;
  dn += (y / 100) * DaysPer100Years;
  y %= 100;
  dn += (y / 4) * DaysPer4Years;
  y %= 4;
  dn += y * DaysPer1Year;
  return dn - epoch;
}

int WeekDay_chux(int year, int Month, int Day) {
  #define WEEK_JAN1AD1_OFFSET 5
  int dow = DayNumber0(year, Month, Day, WEEK_JAN1AD1_OFFSET) % 7;
  return (dow + 7 )%7;
}
```

Note that `DaysPer400Years` is a multiple of 7 (for the [Gregorian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)).  Thus we can take short cuts and start with `year %= 400` to work with smaller numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You probably did something wrong in some code you didn't show.

This works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef enum { So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa } eDayofTheWeek;

int main()
{
  int Day = 5;
  int Month = 12;
  int Year = 2023;
  int w = (Day + floor(2.6 * ((Month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 0.2) + Year % 100 + floor(Year % 100 / 4) + floor(Year / 400) - 2 * floor(Year / 100) - 1);
  
  int Weekday = (w % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
  printf("Weekday = %d\n", Weekday);

  eDayofTheWeek WeekDay = Weekday;
  // add more test code here.
  // maybe the problem is in your test code you didn't show
}
```

Output I get:

```
Weekday = 2
```

Which looks correct to me, 2 being Tuesday. But don't ask me why and how this formula works.

Comment: Jan 1, 2000 was a Saturday (6).  This code reports Monday (1).  Many other mismatches.  Try Oct 1, 2023 for a recent mis-match.

Comment: I used `int Jabberwocky_dow(int Year, int Month, int Day) {
  int w = (Day + floor(2.6 * ((Month + 9) % 12 + 1) - 0.2) + Year % 100 + floor(Year % 100 / 4) + floor(Year / 400) - 2 * floor(Year / 100) - 1);
  int Weekday = (w % 7 + 7) % 7 + 1;
  return Weekday;
}`

Comment: I suspect the formula is correct if it weren't for FPU roundoff. That funny math looks like lookup-table deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the day of week, as others have noted, is not a trivial undertaking.  Ordinarily I like to modify the poster's code and answer with that, but there is a lot going with this calculation:  it is complex.

Here is a solution for discovering the weekday developed sometime back.  It has abundant comments which hopefully explain everything you need to know: why it works, how it works, etc.  It does not resort to std c math library - not needing `floor()` et al.

Runnable code to show it works is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/K36evWz34).

Hope it helps.

EDIT:  Updated code.  Slightly more robust, shorter, and more clarification and details in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Boolean Macro for determining if year argument is a leap year.
// Principle: Each year evenly divisible by 4 is a leap year with the
//            exception of centennials - only centennials evenly divisible
//            by 400 are leap years.
#define IS_LEAP_YEAR(yr) (!((yr)%400) || (!((yr)%4) && (((yr)%100)))  )

char *ascii_days[]={"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 weekday()
 
 Purpose: Given a year, month, and date, return a value (0-6) for
           which day of the week, where 0 = Sunday. 

 Params: year, month, and date, long integers
 
 Notes: uses IS_LEAP_YEAR() macro

 Caveat: The Gregorian Calendar reformed the concept of leap years in Oct 1582 
        to our current leap year concept.  Hence, this code may not produce
        accurate weekdays for dates prior to 1583.  However, it is Proleptic 
        Gregorian Calendar compliant for dates all the way back to 1 AD.  This
        is somewhat of a deep rabbit hole; lots of info is available online.
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int weekday(long year, long month, long date)
{
    long days, wkday, num_lp_yrs;
    int mon;
    int month_days[12]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    /* Notice we say, "year-1" because this parameter year is not complete 
    * and hence not counted.  We will count the days of the current year later. */
    num_lp_yrs = (year-1)/4;  /* How many leap years? One every 4 yrs, but...*/
    num_lp_yrs -= (year-1)/100; /*...centennials are not leap years...*/
    num_lp_yrs += (year-1)/400;   /*...unless that centennial is a multiple of 400*/
    days = (year-1)*365 + num_lp_yrs; /*Capture total number of days*/

    /* If this is a leap year make February 29 days */
    if(IS_LEAP_YEAR(year))
        month_days[1] = 29; 

    /* Now, let's get the days spent of the parameter/'current' (incomplete) year 
    * by examining month and day of the year....because our days count (so far) is
    * only up to January 1st of the parameter year.   Hence, we must add the 
    * days of the current year (since Jan 1st) to the days variable.  Parse
    * and sum every applicable month of the array... */
    for(mon = 0; mon < month-1 && mon < 12; mon++)
        days += month_days[mon];

    /* Finally, add in the parameter date given. */
    days += date;

    /* 7 days in a week, so... modulo 7 nicely tells the weekday*/
    wkday = days%7;

    return (int)wkday;
}


int main() 
{
    int day_of_week = weekday(2023, 12, 5);
    char *sDay = ascii_days[day_of_week];

    printf("Weekday is: %s\n", sDay);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Weekday is: Tue
```

Comment: @Angargedon -- if you use my code please let me know if it works for you, or if you have any questions  -- cheers!

Comment: Look OK for dates since years 1600 to 2400.  (Not a fan of `if(mn < 0) mn=0;`)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  -- Amazing.   Because I was out on a walk a little after posting this  and was really feeling that code block is the weak point, too.   (It's supposed to guard the following loop -- but there is certainly a better way --not sure how to address it just this moment... been a while since I visited it--probly a ```for()``` loop -- not sure why I didn't use that back then, lol) .  Thanks as always for your kind feedback -- always constructive!  I'll likely update in short while.....

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - updated.  I've also added header detail concerning caveat about dates prior to 1583.   Thx again.

Comment: See also [Proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- *Noice*  --I'd never hear of the Proleptic Gregorian calendar 'til now.   Very cool because this weekday() function comes from my "Schedule" app, and for some time now I've wanted to make it accurate to year zero(for fun and interest, mostly).   Think I can close that gap now... thx!

Comment: The majority of the planet was not using the Gregorian Calendar until 1918. So it is easy to fall into some locale issues with even recent dates.  Suggest using  Proleptic Gregorian calendar back to the beginning of time (with year 0 the year before year [AD 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AD_1), and year -1 before that, ...) and form conversion functions, as needed to handle other calendars ,especially [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -- been studying.  If I've understood, my Gregorian Calendar code above is already Proleptic Gregorian Calendar *compliant*.  Because ```Proleptic``` prefix just means we extrapolate Gregorian Calendar rules forward & backward indefinitely [per this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).  Other resources seem to echo same.  And accordingly, such dates will not jive with some Julian dates if we go back far enough -- & may not jive with other societies, their calendars, etc (which you already hinted at).  Have I understood?

Comment: Yep.  For fun [Feb 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-standard_dates#Swedish_calendar).

Comment: @gregspears "_In December of 2011, Samoa and the neighboring island of Tokelau moved the position of the International Date Line, effectively erasing December 31, 2011 from existence._" The fun isn't all decades or centuries in the past...

Comment: @Fe2O3 -- lol, Yes!  This *is* a rabbit hole, deep as oil.   There is also a lot of rich story in varied places.  TIL many countries/cultures have had very unique reasons for what happened and is still happening with their calendars.  Just amazing, and thanks for that add...

Comment: @Angargedon -- if you like/use my code, please consider selecting my answer.  Thank you for your question; I hope I helped regardless.

Answer (score 1):

A test harness should you want to test your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int mktime_dow(int year, int month, int day) {
  struct tm t = {0};
  t.tm_year = year - 1900;
  t.tm_mon = month - 1;
  t.tm_mday = day;
  if (mktime(&t) == -1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return t.tm_wday;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int year = 1600; year <= 2400; year++) {
    for (int mon = 1; mon <= 12; mon++) {
      for (int day = 1; day <= 2; day++) {  // Extend to 28 - 31 if desired.
        int w0 = mktime_dow(year, mon, day);
        int w1 = function under text(year, mon, day);
        if (w0 != w1) {
          printf("%d/%02d/%02d %d != %d\n", year, mon, day, w0, w1);
          exit(1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```